# UInt16[] to EMGU image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv, image-generation

I have an `UInt16` array representing an image and width/height for it, and I would like to turn this into an EMGU image in the least painful way possible.

EMGU has an `Image` constructor that looks promising, which is described [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/84dd94e7-f03f-ceb8-f629-8462326d13a6.htm).

But I can't understand how to format my data, it says that the first dimension is height, but why would I need a whole dimension to describe ONE number? Clearly there is something I don't understand. Something like `Image(ushort[], height, width)` makes more sense to me.

Comment: This is the wrapper of a C lib, thus the arguments are the same. In C arrays are pointers without length information.

Comment: No the arguments are not the same, C doesn't even have constructors so how could they be?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you need to provide:

```
data
Type: TDepth[,,]
The multi-dimensional data
```

where the 1st dimension is # of rows (height),
the 2nd dimension is # cols (width) and
the 3rd dimension is the channel.

So you only need to create a `TDepth[,,]` object (say [Multidimensional Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), and set the three properties: height, width, channel. Something like this:

```
UInt16[,,] depth = new UInt16[, , ] { { height }, { width }, { data } };
```

and `data` - your array with Image data.